# Net Core ApplicationUser with foreign key to itself

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core

I'm using Net Core 2.2 and Entity Framework. I have an ApplicationUser class used for multiple user types with foreign keys to each other but entity framework gives an error when adding a migration:

```
Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation property 'ApplicationUser.Class' of type 'Class'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.
```

I'm unsure what the proper way to implement this is. Can anyone help me?

My ApplicationUser class:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string TeacherId { get; set; }
    public int? ClassId { get; set; }
    public int? SettingsId { get; set; }

    public virtual ApplicationUser Customer { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser Teacher { get; set; }
    public virtual Class Class { get; set; }
    public virtual Settings Settings { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Class> Classes { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<License> Licenses { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Exercise> Exercises { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<GameProgress> GameProgresses { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<StudentExercise> StudentExercises { get; set; }
}
```

And because it's in the error, my Class class:

```
public class Class
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string TeacherId { get; set; }
    public int? SettingsId { get; set; }

    public virtual ApplicationUser Teacher { get; set; }
    public virtual Settings Setting { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Exercise> Exercises { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUser> Students { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with self-referential `ApplicationUser` relationships. The exception specifically tells you this is a problem with `Class`. The issue is that you've got a reference property to `Class` on `ApplicationUser`, but on `Class`, you've got both a collection of `ApplicationUser`s (`Students`) and a separate reference to `ApplicationUser` (`Teacher`). Simply, EF doesn't know which this foreign key is actually referring to.

The solution is exactly what the exception tells you: add fluent config to clear up the ambiguity:

```
public override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
        .HasOne(x => x.Class)
        .WithMany(x => x.Students);
}
```

Comment: Ugh, thank you Chris. You are, as always, a great help.